# Relations that don't belong to area are being added to the result set

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I want to query all counties in Czech republic. I am using this query:

```
[date:"2023-07-09T00:00:00Z"];
area["ISO3166-1"="CZ"]->.boundaryarea;
(
  rel(area.boundaryarea)[boundary=administrative][admin_level=6];
);
out geom;
```

Which produces this result. As you can see, there are relations from Germany that spill into the Czech area (crossed out with red).

[image: Image of query outcome]

How can I filter out relations that only touch the queried area but are not part of it?
I would later like to use the same technique to query states of different countries, national parks, and more. So I would like the solution to be versatile, not just a one time fix for this query.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional condition to include only elements that are also tagged with `ISO3166-2=CZ-...`:

```
[date:"2023-07-09T00:00:00Z"];
area["ISO3166-1"="CZ"]->.boundaryarea;
(
  rel(area.boundaryarea)[boundary=administrative][admin_level=6]["ISO3166-2"~"^CZ-"];
);
out geom;
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you, this works well for states, however, I would like to use it for boundary=protected_area as well, and they don't have the ISO.. tag.